# uncaught reference error $ is not defined ajax-jquery

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I'm trying to pass some variables using jquery and ajax but for some reason its not working. Here is the code.

```
<div id=' . $result['game_id'] . ' name="' . $user_id . '"  class="rate_widget" >
            <div class="star_1 ratings_stars"></div>
            <div class="star_2 ratings_stars"></div>
            <div class="star_3 ratings_stars"></div>
            <div class="star_4 ratings_stars"></div>
            <div class="star_5 ratings_stars"></div>
            <div class="total_votes">vote data</div>
        </div>
```

when i check chrome's developer tools i can see that the id and name attributes are set correctly .

Here is the javascript(using jquery) i put an alert box to see if the value was set but i get undefined. Just started learning ajax and jquery this week any help would be appreciated.

```
$('.rate_widget').each(function() {
        var widget = this;
        var out_data = {
            game_id : $(widget).attr('id'),
            user_id : $(widget).attr('name')
        };
        alert(game_id);
        $.post(
            'ratings.php',
            out_data,
            function(INFO) {
                $(widget).data( 'fsr', INFO );
                set_votes(widget);
            },
            'json'
        );
```

In case its not clear im trying to send game_id and user_id with the corresponding values to a php script but im getting the error. Also i know there is another question with the same name but i checked it and it didn't help.

Comment: Check if jQuery is being loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reference `game_id` like that.  `game_id` is an index in the `out_data` object.

To alert the correct value you'd have to use :

```
alert(out_data['game_id']);
```

I'd also recommend wrapping your object indexes with quotes - just to make it a little more readable -

```
var out_data = {
  'game_id' : $(widget).attr('id'),
  'user_id' : $(widget).attr('name')
};
```

Comment: that wasn't the answer but it led me to the right answer so i guess you get the accepted answer

Comment: @hugoismyname If it's not the issue, can you explain what was the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you put your javascript inside this ?

```
$( document ).ready( function(){
     // .. your code
})
```

Your javascript must have run before your php finished generating html.